# Reading CSV data using Sql Server Import Export Utility

Tags: excel, csv, ssis, excel-2007, opencsv

I am reading a CSV file using SSIS tool but problem is that data which I read is in wrong format means to say data of columns mismatch. Like Note column data which contains message comes in Id column etc. I tried all types of separator and text qualifier but did't help me.

Main problem is that excel is able to show data in correct format but SSIS is not. I want to know why it is happen or I am missing something.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If its a csv file, do not open in Excel. Use a Wordpad(preferable) or a notepad to view the data. Find out what the delimiter is and give it a try. That might help you out.

Comment: I know what is missing but problem is that why excel is able to show data in correct format? What type of delimiters and encoding excel used to read data.